# DateTime conversation throws 'can't dup Fixnum'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, jruby, fixnum

I have a form on Ruby on Rails 4.0 with jruby 1.7.9. and I use Mongoid instead of ActiveRecord.

When I submit my form with a DateTime object and an Attachment (multipart file) it throws the error 'can't dup Fixnum'. The application stores the DateTime object as a Unix timestamp within the database.

If I submit the form without the DateTime it saves the Attachment successfully. If I submit the form without an Attachment it saves the DateTime as expected. When both are implemented it throws an error.

How can I fix this?

Full Error message is:

```
can't dup Fixnum
Extracted source (around line #222):

220 self.data[name] = DateTime.parse(value).to_time.to_i
221 when 'datetime'
222 self.data[name] = DateTime.parse(value).to_time.to_i
223 when 'time'
224 self.data[name] = DateTime.parse(value).to_time.to_i
225 when 'number'

Rails.root: /Users/mehmetdavut/Documents/
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/models/content.rb:222:in `change_property_types'
app/models/content.rb:214:in `change_property_types'
app/controllers/contents_controller.rb:56:in `update'

Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"patch",
 "authenticity_token"=>"viv0CO7QKSY8kklTiLAXpdGkqv2W7fiW3Zrf2ZnKjpc=",
 "content"=>{"data"=>{"second_datetime"=>"2014-04-07 17:20:00"},
 "url"=>"",
 "language_id"=>"ffef8bca0000ffd4b4cee70e",
 "device_id"=>"52eeb9964d65682809130000",
 "template_id"=>"fff02c4d0000a37cc11eed8f",
 "layout_id"=>"fff02c760000a37cc11eed90",
 "access"=>{"requires_authentication"=>"0",
 "requires_ssl"=>"0"},
 "discoverability"=>{"title"=>"",
 "description"=>"",
 "keywords"=>"",
 "sitemap_change_frequency"=>"",
 "sitemap_priority"=>"",
 "exclude_from_search"=>"0"},
 "menu"=>{"alias"=>"",
 "class"=>"",
 "passive"=>"0",
 "script"=>"",
 "show_in_navigation"=>"0",
 "show_in_sitemap"=>"0"},
 "taxonomy"=>{"category_id"=>"",
 "tags"=>""},
 "published_at"=>"2014-03-14T12:01:24-08:00",
 "unpublished_at"=>""},
 "attachments"=>{"second_file"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x162cbfcf @original_filename="Screen Shot 2014-03-13 at 00.38.30.png",
 @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"attachments[second_file]\"; filename=\"Screen Shot 2014-03-13 at 00.38.30.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n",
 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/cs/6xmggtv54nq8l2xw77mzhtcr0000gn/T/RackMultipart20140314-18002-csbpyn>,
 @content_type="image/png">},
 "commit"=>"Update Content",
 "page_id"=>"fff02ce20000a37cc11eed96",
 "id"=>"fff02ce20000a37cc11eed97"}
```

This is "change_property_types" method:

```
def change_property_types
  self.data.each do |name, value|
    property = self.page.document.properties.where(name: name).first

    unless value.blank?
      case property.type
      when 'date'
        self.data[name] = DateTime.parse(value).to_time.to_i
      when 'datetime'
        self.data[name] = DateTime.parse(value).to_time.to_i
      when 'time'
        self.data[name] = DateTime.parse(value).to_time.to_i
      when 'number'
        self.data[name] = value.to_i
      when 'file'
        # self.attachments << Attachment.create(file: value)
      else
        self.data[name] = value
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: can you give full stack trace ? Nothing wrong I am seeing here `self.data[name] = DateTime.parse(value).to_time.to_i` ..

Comment: Please share `change_property_types` method from `app/models/content.rb`.

Comment: @KirtiThorat I edited question above with change_property_types method. Thank you

Comment: What are `name` and `value` when it falls over?

Comment: "name" is field name and "value" is what it have to store. For example, i build a form and there area "first_name, last_name, age" fields. When someone fill that form mongodb stores it at data field like: 
 
self.data['first_name'] = "Mehmet" 
self.data['last_name'] = "Davut" 
self.data['age'] = 26

... So, sometimes user build a form with datetime field and file upload field. This error happens when these both are filled. But, for example, it works when user not select a file for upload.

Comment: Mu is too short meant to ask the actual values of the variables "name" and "value" when you have the error. You can put line 222 into a begin, rescue block to be able to print out the values. Even better if you put "debugger" into the rescue block there so you can examine the variables.

Comment: I think it's important to know what the actual values of `name` and `value` are at this point in the code before an answer can be given.

Comment: Let me reformulate this, could you put `puts "name="+name, "value="+value` in front of your current line 222 and provide us with the output? Otherwise there is no way of knowing what String `DateTime.parse` is trying to parse and therefore to actually answer  your question.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because value is a fixnum.
What is the output of the following code?

```
...
when 'datetime'
  raise value.class.inspect
...
```

what does your form look like?

And what happens if you do:

```
unless value.blank?
    case property.type
    when 'date'
        self.data[name] = DateTime.parse(value.to_s).to_time.to_i
    when 'datetime'
        self.data[name] = DateTime.parse(value.to_s).to_time.to_i
    when 'time'
        self.data[name] = DateTime.parse(value.to_s).to_time.to_i
    when 'number'
        self.data[name] = value.to_i
    when 'file'
        # self.attachments << Attachment.create(file: value)
    else
        self.data[name] = value
    end
end
```

Comment: Even if `value` is a Fixnum, that does not explain the error `can't dup Fixnum`. `DateTime.parse` with some `Fixnum` as argument throws a `TypeError` which is a different error. It is also not explained why the error described by the OP only occurs when he submits a DateTime + attachment, but does not occur when he submits either of those. All in all, I don't think this answer is complete, or even accurate. Since you ask a lot of questions, it's more like a comment.

Comment: I reproduced the exact same error with DateTime.parse(123) on Rails 3.2.14 and jruby 1.7.10, that much to "which is a different error".

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of duplication in your code. This makes it very dense and hard to track down your error. I might refactor as such. Note: This is untested re factor of your code

```
# DRY up your code :)

def change_property_types
  data.each do |name, value|
    next if value.blank?
    self.data[name] = if get_property_type =~ /file/i
      set_attachments(value)
    elsif value.present? && check_dateishness
      DateTime.parse(value).to_time.to_i
    else
      value
    end
  end
end

private

def check_dateishness 
  %w(date datetime time).include?(get_property_type)
end

# handle the case where attachements may be nil. 
def set_attachements(value)
  if self.attachments.blank?
    self.attachments = [Attachment.create(file: value)] 
  else
    self.attachments << Attachment.create(file: value)
  end
end

# You could probably memoize this... i.e. @some_var ||= ...
def get_property_type
  page.document.properties.where(name: name).first.type
end
```

or you could decompose your code more.

```
# Or decompose it to better track down errors
...

def change_property_types
  data.each do |name, value|
    next if value.blank?
    if property_type =~ /file/
      # you need to handle the attachments.nil?
      attachments << Attachment.create(file: value)
    else
      data[name] = parse_it(property).to_i
    end
  end
end

private

def property_type
  @property ||= page.document.properties \
    .where(name: name).first.type
end

# Really this case statement can be simplified
# as you could check the class of the object, i.e.
# value.is_a?(Date) or value.is_a?(Time) and since
# the only Ruby class that needs to_time is Date 
# you simplify the code
def parse_it(value)
  case value.type
  when 'time'     then time_parser(value)
  when 'date'     then date_parser(value)
  when 'datetime' then datetime_parser(value)
  else               value
  end
end

def date_parser(date)
  return date.to_time if date.is_a?(Date)
  Date.parse(date.to_s).to_time
end

# Time has a to_i function
def time_parser(time)
  return time if time.is_a?(Time)
  Time.parse(time.to_s)
end

# DateTime has a to_i function
def datetime_parser(datetime)
  return datetime if datetime.is_a?(DateTime)
  DateTime.parse(datetime.to_s)
end

...
```